# How To Create docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am a beginner in docker so I have no good knowledge but I am keen to learn more. So I hope this community can guide me.
Now I have a Dockerfile.

```
# getting base image debian
 FROM debian
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vsftpd
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ftp
 RUN apt-get install nano
 RUN sudo sed -i.$(date +%F) '/^#/d;/^$/d' /etc/vsftpd.conf

# Add configuration in /etc/vsftpd.conf
 RUN echo "write_enable=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf
 RUN echo "chroot_local_user=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf
 RUN echo "user_sub_token=\$USER" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf
 RUN echo "local_root=/home/\$USER/ftp" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf
 RUN echo "userlist_enable=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf
 RUN echo "pasv_min_port=40000" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf
 RUN echo "pasv_max_port=50000" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf
 RUN echo "userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf
 RUN echo "userlist_deny=NO" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf

# create new group "zanui"  
RUN groupadd zanui
#user "lal" with group lal
RUN useradd -G zanui --system --create-home --no-log-init lal
RUN echo "lal:123456" | chpasswd

RUN useradd -G zanui --system --create-home --no-log-init mausam
RUN echo "mausam:123456" | chpasswd

RUN echo "lal" | sudo tee -a /etc/vsftpd.userlist
RUN echo "mausam" | sudo tee -a /etc/vsftpd.userlist

RUN mkdir /home/lal/ftp
RUN chown nobody:nogroup /home/lal/ftp
RUN chmod a-w /home/lal/ftp

RUN mkdir /home/lal/ftp/files
RUN sudo chown lal:lal /home/lal/ftp/files

RUN mkdir /home/mausam/ftp
RUN chown nobody:nogroup /home/mausam/ftp
RUN chmod a-w /home/mausam/ftp

RUN mkdir /home/mausam/ftp/files
RUN sudo chown mausam:mausam /home/mausam/ftp/files

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential git libfuse-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev mime-support automake libtool pkg-config libssl-dev
RUN git clone https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse
WORKDIR /s3fs-fuse
RUN ./autogen.sh && ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-openssl && make && make install
WORKDIR /../
ADD /conf/passwd-s3fs /etc/passwd-s3fs
RUN chmod 600 /etc/passwd-s3fs

# RUN s3fs bucket-name /home/lal/ftp/files
```

First I build the image from Dockerfile using the command:

```
docker build -t mydebiantest1:1.0 .
```

Then I run the container using this image using the following command:

```
docker run --privileged -it mydebiantest1:1.0 bash
```

Then I will be inside Debian Linux bash instance

```
root@c875e352e4e7:/#
```

So now what I want is that how can run these steps when I run the command :

```
docker-compose up
```

Somehow I have managed to build docker-compose.yml file which seems not working what I want.

```
version: '3'
services:
  # The Application
  s3bucketftp:
    container_name: s3bucketftp
    image: s3bucketftp:1.0
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        environment: development
```

Comment: What is the expected result? To build the image and run it as a container via compose?

Comment: i was asked to do these steps using docker-command so the user dont need to do anything for the setup.

Comment: Your first step should be to set things up so that `docker run mydebiantest1:1.0` launches the server and not an interactive shell; you'll need a `CMD` line in there.  (You also might strip out some of the unnecessary and/or dangerous things, like plain-text hard-coded login credentials.)  If you can do that, the `docker-compose.yml` file you show should more or less work.  If it doesn't, you should edit the question to include a description of what it does do and what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Dockerfile` does not have either `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`. If launching a container to use interactively as the objective, then add

```
CMD /bin/bash
```

You need not provide both `image` and `build` context for your service. You need a pre-built tagged image either locally or in the docker repository if the `image` attribute is specified.

Instead let the docker to `build` a new image based on the provided `context`.

The updated `docker-compose.yaml` would look like,

```
version: '3'
services:
  s3bucketftp:
    container_name: s3bucketftp
    privileged: true
    tty: true
    build:
      context: ./
      args:
        environment: development
```

With this compose file, you can build the image and start the container (please note that you have run the compose commands from the same location as your compose file).

Also note that this service cannot be scaled as the `container_name` is specified.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

`-d` is to run the container as the background process

And check for running container,

```
docker-compose ps
```

Once the container is running, the container can be accessed directly without having to redo any of the setup.

```
docker exec -it s3bucketftp /bin/bash
```

Comment: thank for your time. So can i ask you one thing. Is there anyway to run command for mounting s3fs  "s3fs bucket_name /home/lal/ftp/files" when docker exec ?

Comment: After you exec into the container, it opens an interactive shell. you can run the `s3fs` command in there.

Comment: when i run docker-compose up, i get 
[Warning] One or more build-args [environment] were not consumed
Successfully built d3a87de2eddf
Successfully tagged s3bucketasftp_s3bucketftp:latest
Starting s3bucketftp ... done
Attaching to s3bucketftp
s3bucketftp    |
s3bucketftp exited with code 0

And when i do "docker ps", nothing to display.

Comment: Well, that is because your `Dockerfile` does not contain any `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` instruction in it. You can set `tty: true` in your compose file (Refer updated answer). But this will timeout if the container is unused within the timeout period. I suggest you add a long running process in your `Dockerfile` or set the environment variable `COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=<seconds>` before `docker-compose up`

Comment: PS F:\practice\docker\ausprojects\s3bucketasftp> docker exec -it s3bucketftp bash     
Error response from daemon: Container 16d5704510a064d7153009f5eebfc26e5985921e932fcd2298c2d0b4278010c5 is not 
running... how can i make the container running? can you give me any links so i do research

Comment: You have to add some `CMD` in your `Dockerfile` to keep the container running. Add this `CMD /bin/bash` at the end of your Dockerfile and try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210800/discussion-between-lal-kumar-rai-and-franklinsijo).

Comment: thanks man it is working. But i am curious about one thing... when i run command "docker exec -it s3bucketftp bash" it opens terminal of debian thats fine, but later i have run s3fs buket_name mount_folder_src. Can i get mounted s3fs already when i run the command "docker exec -it s3bucketftp bash" ?

Comment: You can do that either in compose or in the dockerfile itself. The container will start with mounted s3fs. But to mount while `exec`, AFAIK it is not possible with `-it`.

Comment: then we can mount when building image?

Comment: when i run the line, it give me error "fuse device not found try 'modprobe fuse' first" and when run command "modprobe fuse", it says command not found. This problem was solved when i run the container with privileged option i.e docker run --privilieged -it containername bash

Comment: Sorry, yes docker build does not support privileged operations and mounting of a device is not going to be possible during build. I suggest you post a new question for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set up many containers at one time you need to configure docker-compose file and that's all. You needn't build the container from the image manually. It docker-compose does when first time builds and runs containers.

Create an empty folder called 'docker' and inside 'docker' directory create a directory with the name 's3', put there your docker file there.
Move there and there in terminal type:

```
touch docker-compose.yml
vim docker-compose.yml
```

Put there this content

```
version: '2'

services:
  # The Application
  s3bucketftp:
    container_name: s3bucketftp
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./s3/Dockerfile
      args:
        environment: development
```

If you want to open a terminal in some specific container you should use the command:

```
docker exec -it {containerName} /bin/bash
```

If it won't work, you should try to give as second argument executable terminal, so in final your command to go inside the container will be

```
docker exec -it {containerName} {pathToExecutableInContainer}
```

Comment: You also can go to my github(etvsyaka) and look there to docker repository. It's my own template for dockerized Symfony applications.

Comment: ok i can build image and run container but i want to run command be like "docker run --privileged -it mydebiantest1:1.0 bash"

Comment: In case you want to work as a container's root user you should write in a terminal.

Comment: @LalKumarRai I updated the answer. I hope you'll get what you need. If something - just write,

Comment: @Vasly thank for your time. So can i ask you one thing. Is there anyway to run command for mounting s3fs  "s3fs bucket_name /home/lal/ftp/files" when docker exec ?

Comment: When i run docker-compose up, i get 
[Warning] One or more build-args [environment] were not consumed
Successfully built d3a87de2eddf
Successfully tagged s3bucketasftp_s3bucketftp:latest
Starting s3bucketftp ... done
Attaching to s3bucketftp
s3bucketftp    |
s3bucketftp exited with code 0

And when i do "docker ps", nothing to display.